# What does "sharp design" mean in Chaisemartin (2020)'s paper compared to Goodman-Bacon (2017)'s paper?

Tags: difference-in-difference, treatment-effect, heterogeneity

When studying the paper of [Chaisemartin (2020)](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.20181169) comparing to [Goodman-Bacon, 2017](https://www.nber.org/papers/w25018#:%7E:text=The%20canonical%20difference%2Din%2Ddifferences,receive%20treatment%20at%20different%20times.)'s paper regarding heterogeneous treatment effects, a commentator said that Chaisermartin's papers have more of a **sharp design** or a general design. I am wondering what does "**sharp design**" means in this case.